# Uso do pronome oblíquo quando o verbo está no gerúndio

Tags: português-brasileiro, sintaxe, pronomes-oblíquos

Ao [ler esse artigo](https://revistas.ufpr.br/historia/article/viewFile/30564/19760), identifiquei a frase a seguir:

> McCann vem se debruçando sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política dos militares há mais de trinta anos

No ínicio — “McCann vem se debruçando” — não seria correto o uso do pronome depois do verbo, como indica o uso da ênclise,

> Nas orações reduzidas de gerúndio (desde que não venham precedidas de preposição "em")

Caso precedidas de *em*, usamos a próclise.

Comment: Então você gostaria de saber por que foi fraseado “vem se debruçando” se a regra de gerúndio dita o uso de ênclise?

Comment: Sim, o correto no meio ver seria: `vem debruçando se`

Comment: *McCann vem se debruçando sobre os problemas* **não** é uma oração reduzida de gerúndio. Uma oração reduzida de gerúndio é uma oração subordinada em que o gerúndio desempenha o papel de demonstrar a subordinação. Por exemplo, *Debruçando-se sobre o papel dos militares, McCann concluiu que...* Por isso, a regra citada não se aplica. É "vem se debruçando" mesmo, e não "vem debruçando-se", que aliás soa horrorosamente.

Comment: @luisHenrique o que você acha de transformar seu comentário em resposta?

Comment: @AiltonAndradedeOliveira - Feito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frase está de acordo com a gramática do português brasileiro.

Antes de mais, a regra enunciada é válida, com a ressalva de que não só a preposição *em* força a próclise, como também o facto de se tratar de uma oração negativa, ou de haver um quantificador (*poucos*, *muitos*) ou certos advérbios. Mas como foi já referido, o exemplo que dás não tem uma oração gerundiva, tem antes uma perífrase verbal com o verbo *vir*.

A frase que dás também não é válida de acordo com a gramática do português europeu. Tem de haver ênclise nessa frase (mas não por causa da regra que dás), por isso as duas opções seriam:

> 1. McCann **vem-se debruçando** sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política dos militares há mais de trinta anos.
> 2. ?McCann **vem debruçando-se** sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política dos militares há mais de trinta anos

A segunda frase é marginal no português europeu a partir do século XX. Havendo uma perífrase com um gerúndio, a subida do clítico para o verbo auxiliar é praticamente obrigatória.

A frase que dás é parecida a 1., mas a ausência de hífen indica que se trata não de uma ênclise ao verbo auxiliar, mas de uma próclise ao verbo principal. Isto não é de maneira nenhuma possível no português europeu, mas é-o no brasileiro. Por exemplo, a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian menciona numa nota de rodapé:

> No português brasileiro, a cliticização ao particípio passado é possível desde que este seja parte de uma perífrase. Nas perífrases verbais com particípio passado bem como nas perífrases verbais com gerúndio, os átonos cliticizam, em próclise, à forma não finita do verbo:
>       a. Ela não tinha [lhe apresentado] o amigo. [português brasileiro]
>       b. Ela não estava [lhe dando] atenção. [português brasileiro]

Answer (score 3):

Nem toda oração que contém um gerúndio é uma oração "reduzida de gerúndio".

Uma oração reduzida de gerúndio é uma oração subordinada, em que a conjunção subordinativa é substituída pelo uso do verbo principal no gerúndio.

Por exemplo, na frase seguinte,

> Se quiser voltar para casa, peça.

Temos duas orações, *Peça*, que é a principal, e *Se quiser voltar para casa*, que é a subordinada, e explica em que condições é para pedir.

Essa oração subordinada pode ser "reduzida", usando-se um gerúndio:

> Querendo voltar para casa, peça.

Mas na frase

> McCann vem se debruçando sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação
>   política dos militares há mais de trinta anos.

não há nenhuma oração subordinada. Debruçar-se aí é o verbo principal. O gerúndio  neste caso indica o tempo (presente) e o aspecto verbal (contínuo) - McCann está se debruçando agora, não amanhã, e também não começou agora. Não indica subordinação.

Por isso, a regra não se aplica neste caso.

Para sentir melhor a diferença, eis uma frase sobre McCann e os militares que contém de fato uma oração reduzida de gerúndio:

> Debruçando-se sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política dos militares há mais de trinta anos, McCann concluiu que é melhor que eles deixem a política para os políticos.

Aqui sim temos uma oração composta: McCann concluiu que é melhor que os militares não se metam em política. Por quê? Por que se debruçou sobre a atuação política deles. A oração não reduzida é

> McCann concluiu que é melhor que os militares deixem a política para os políticos, pois se debruça sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política deles há mais de trinta anos.

Veja que aqui a ênclise não é somente por que "não se começa frase com próclise":

> McCann concluiu que é melhor que os militares deixem a política para os políticos, debruçando-se sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política deles há mais de trinta anos.

---

Ainda assim, a regra me parece um tanto ou quanto preciosista. Não vejo por que seria errado, ou deselegante, dizer, ou escrever,

> McCann concluiu que é melhor que os militares deixem a política para os políticos, se debruçando sobre os problemas concernentes à atuação política deles há mais de trinta anos.

Parece mais um daqueles casos em que os gramáticos normativos querem congelar a língua no século XIX...

Comment: Vale lembrar que no Brasil preferimos ênclises, mesmo em início de frase. Acredito que muitos brasileiros escrevem frases como "Amo-te" a contragosto, pois soa artificial, já que normalmente dizemos "Te amo".

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira - Você quis dizer próclises, claro. Mas o raciocínio está correto. "Amo-te" soa artificial, e na verdade, desagradável. E é completamente desusado no Brasil, a não ser talvez em romances de época, ou como galhofa.

Comment: Sim, sim, isso mesmo. Me confundi. Obrigado.